# Search and replace missing lines in the data structure by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

My data files have many missing lines (these are time series data). I would like to find

The location of these missing lines (the missing of values at time points) and replace them with the lines with nan.

For this purpose, I used pandas. However, it took too much time. So, I even couldn't check whether my code is really working or not.

```
for INPUT in FileList:

data=pd.read_csv(INPUT,sep='#',index_col=[1],parse_dates=[1])
print data
start = data.head(1).index
end = data.tail(1).index

timestamp = pd.date_range('2013-07-01 00:00:00','2013-09-30 23:59:00',freq="T")

N=timestamp.size

cr =pd.DataFrame(NA,columns=data.columns,index=timestamp)

for i in range(N):

   s="%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d"%(timestamp.year[i],timestamp.month[i],timestamp.hour[i], 
       timestamp.minute[i])               
   try:
       cr.ix[timestamp[i]]=data.ix[s]
   except ValueError:
      print INPUT,s,"ValueError"
   except KeyError:
      print INPUT,s,"KeyError"
   output = FileList[i] + "result"
```

If you have any idea to reduce running time of this code, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Your English is not clear, so I'm not really sure what the input is or what your program does, but--in the worst case--you can extend Python with C for this bit of code: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: @NewWorld Thank you for your advice, I apologize that my question is not clear. The inputs are the time series of meteorological data for 3 months and this code is for constructing data structure to sort the lines of time point which is missing. for example 2014/03/12/03:11, 2014/03/12/03:12. 2014/03/12/03:14. In this case 2014/03/12/03:13 is missing. After finding missing time lines, I would like to fill those time lines with nan's. Is that clearer explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sample series by taking 100k rows from the regular index, simulating your read_csv

```
In [22]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)

In [23]: index = pd.date_range('2013-07-01 00:00:00','2013-09-30 23:59:00',freq="T")

In [24]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000),index=index.take(np.sort(np.random.choice(range(len(index)),100000,replace=False))))

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
                            0
2013-07-01 00:00:00  0.009764
2013-07-01 00:01:00  0.900823
2013-07-01 00:02:00 -1.718848
2013-07-01 00:04:00  0.197763
2013-07-01 00:05:00 -0.269920
...                       ...
2013-09-30 23:54:00  0.368947
2013-09-30 23:55:00  1.488926
2013-09-30 23:57:00  0.749575
2013-09-30 23:58:00  0.964609
2013-09-30 23:59:00  0.112557

[100000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Reindex

```
In [26]: df.reindex(index)
Out[26]: 
                            0
2013-07-01 00:00:00  0.009764
2013-07-01 00:01:00  0.900823
2013-07-01 00:02:00 -1.718848
2013-07-01 00:03:00       NaN
2013-07-01 00:04:00  0.197763
...                       ...
2013-09-30 23:55:00  1.488926
2013-09-30 23:56:00       NaN
2013-09-30 23:57:00  0.749575
2013-09-30 23:58:00  0.964609
2013-09-30 23:59:00  0.112557

[132480 rows x 1 columns]
```

You can also do `df.asfreq('T')`, though that has slightly different end-point semantics (e.g. the series will start/stop at the last period in your sample)

Comment: I really appreciate your advice. I think that your code would be really useful for my purpose. So, is it right that I can exchange "np.random.randn(100000) in DataFrame with my original data? Anyway thank you.

Comment: well I would use your ``read_csv`` in place of the ``DataFrame`` creation, but yes.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. I got your point. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Jeff, I have another question. I follow your advice and an expected result. However, for missing lines, my result shows ",,,,,.." instead of filling with "Nan". Did I miss something to fill with "NaN"? Thank you.

Comment: it's showing a truncated display, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#display-changes